# Custom Jackson 2 ObjectMapper doesn't always get used after Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jackson

We are using a custom Jackson 2 ObjectMapper that ignores invalid properties in JSON requests when serializing to a POJO. This odd thing is happening where after a build using Maven the custom ObjectMapper is being used as expected, and then other time it is not (seems to be using default maybe). The reason we know it isn't using the custom one is invalid properties are not being ignored during serialization and a 400 is being returned in our Jersey 2.9.1 resource. Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening and what could be done to fix it to always use the custom mapper?

pom file:

```
<!-- Start inherited dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like an maven dependencies issue, one time your maven uses version 1 of dep A the other time it uses version 2 of dep A. Best way is to check your dependency tree and explicitly exclude all unwanted version in your pom file.

Comment: So just specifying the version wouldn't be enough? It looks like our inherited dependencies weren't specifying a version currently in the pom file.

Comment: No, specifying the versions is not enough if one of your dependencies depends on another version of the one you are using :) Welcome to maven dependency hell. Your issue sounds like one of these problems because sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: I will investigate this more and see if doing this will fix the issue.

Comment: When you say all unwanted versions, are you referring to the dependency in question (Jackson), or the transitive dependencies?

Comment: All transitive dependencies. Its never good to have a dep. which specifies another version of another dep. you are explicitly using :)